# Primefaces Dialog closes when called the second time

Tags: primefaces, dialog

I have a datatable, with a command Button in each row,

The issue is that when i need to open one dialog for the first one, and then by clicking on another button, i need to update it. The issue is when i click on the second button, it closes the dialog and the user have to click once again on the second button to open the dialog again!

Thank's in advance for your help,

i'm here for further explanation

Answer (score 0):

to my knowldege,You can open as many dialog as you want, only make sure that you gave them a unique widgetVar id:

```
  <p:dialog widgetVar="dlg1">
  <h:outputText value="Hello from first dialog"/> 
</p:dialog>
<p:dialog widgetVar="dlg2">
  <h:outputText value="Hello from second dialog"/>
</p:dialog>
```

...

```
<p:commandButton value="Open First" onclick="dlg1.show()"/>
<p:commandButton value="Open Second" onclick="dlg2.show()"/>
```

Clicking on the commandButton above will open two separate dialog parallelly.

Answer (score 0):

I think your buttons made an update to the entire `Naming Container` that wraps your `Dialog`. If u do that, that's what you get.

You should update `Container` inside your Dialog that wraps your component inside.

Example :
Don't :

```
<h:panelGrid id="gridContainer">
  <p:dialog id="dialogComponent>

   // components

  </p:dialog>
</h:panelGrid>

<p:commandButton update="#{p:component('gridContainer')}"/>
```

Do :

```
<h:panelGrid id="gridContainer">
  <p:dialog id="dialogComponent>

     <h:panelGrid id="insideContainer">
        // components
     </h:panelGrid>

  </p:dialog>
</h:panelGrid>

<p:commandButton update="#{p:component('insideContainer')}"/>
```

I think you get the idea.
Hope it helps.